# Not able to download selenium-server log from the saucelab, getting FilenotFound Exception

Tags: saucelabs

I am not able to download selenium-server log from the saucelab

This is the error:

> Sep 07, 2021 9:27:43 PM com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST saveFile
> WARNING: Error downloading Sauce Results
> java.io.FileNotFoundException :

This is the code:

```
SauceREST sauceREST = new SauceREST(username, accesskey);
sauceREST.downloadLog(sessionid, "/target/saucelab");
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because either:

1. Your network infrastructure is blocking requests to the REST API
2. The test you're grabbing logs for hasn't finalised asset upload

Check whether you can download the logs manually ([docs here](https://docs.saucelabs.com/dev/api/jobs/#get-a-job-asset-file)):

```
curl -u "$SAUCE_USERNAME:$SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY" --location \
--request GET 'https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/rest/v1/{USERNAME}/jobs/{JOB_ID}/assets/log.json'
```

If you can, try wrapping your REST code in a try/catch block, and if it fails, wait a small amount of time and try again.